# Ajax call to PHP script slows whole webpage down when the PostgreSQL connection is not possible

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, postgresql

We have a website that mainly uses MySQL but there is one chart on the site which uses a PostgreSQL database. This latter database is sometimes down because of the company which maintains it.

To counteract this problem I have used Ajax to get the data for the chart. After everything else has loaded on the webpage, Ajax is used to call a PHP page which gets data from the PostgreSQL database. However this has not resolved the issue. All the other link clicks on the webpage don't work until the database connection attempt has returned an error.

Isn't Ajax supposed to be asynchronous so that we can use other parts of the page even if the ajax call is slow?

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Yes ajax is asynchronous, it should not block the UI while the request is made. Do you have code available?

Comment: As @Trace says if Ajax is asynchronous it should not block the UI at all and you should add a code source to check your Ajax call and php code